# Excluding results in has_many :through relation in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise

I am trying to select groups which the @current_user is NOT a member of

The relevant parts of my models are as follows:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :group_memberships 
    has_many :members, :class_name => "User", :through=>:group_memberships
 ...

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :group_memberships, :foreign_key => 'member_id'
    has_many :groups, :through => :group_memberships
...

class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :member, :class_name=>"User"  
    belongs_to :group
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and do something like:

```
@groups = Group.where("id NOT IN (?)", current_user.groups)
```

More information can be found in the [Active Record Query](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions).

Comment: Ah.. that is actually more practical than the previous answer.. and fairly obvious. Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: @groups = Group.where("id NOT IN (?)", current_user.groups) ... but yes thanks!

Comment: No problem. Find it much more efficient also

Answer (score 0):

have a method like this:

```
def group_ids_not_a_member_of
  # get all group_ids and subtract out the ids that he is a member of
  Group.pluck('id') - current_user.groups.map(&:id) 
end
```

then

```
user.group_ids_not_a_member_of
```

Comment: Awesome. Seems to be working. Can you direct me to some documentation on the - operator?

Comment: basically Group.pluck('id') will give you back all the group ids, the  second part is an array of the group ids of that current user. Since it is just an array of integers, you can do subtraction on it (ie Array1 - Array2). http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D